# Need ideas how to save a list to a server using jquery ajax and php apache?

Tags: jquery

Need ideas how to save the list below to a server using jquery ajax and php apache?

```
      <ul>     
          <li> Test Results A </li>
          <li> Test Results B </li>
          <li> Test Results C </li>
          <li> Test Results D </li>
          <li> Test Results E </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: You mean ideas beyond "Submit with `$.ajax()`, store in database from PHP"? Are you using a particular database on your webserver?

Comment: So what, do you want to write it to a log file on your server, or...? Please clarify what you mean by "save", and if you aren't using a database how do you intend to deal with multiple saves from repeat visits to your page? (And please follow the link from darkajax's comment.)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of resources on this, here is one of them: http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/